# How do I get a drop down window under the appBar in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

```
appBar: AppBar(toolbarHeight: 100,
  automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
  elevation: 10,
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,

  title: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: [
      SizedBox(height:30),
      Row(
        children: [
          Icon(Icons.home_rounded,
            color: HexColor('#24591C'),),
          Text('Home',
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontSize:   16,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700
            ),),
          Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down_rounded,
              size: 30,
              color: HexColor('#444444')),
        ],
      ),
      Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 2),
        child: Text('B Block, NCC Aster Park...',
          style: TextStyle(
              color: HexColor('#999999'),
              fontSize: 11
          ),),
      )
    ],
  ),
```

[image]

I need the dropdown to show up when clicking on the 'home' text which I have declared under the title of the appbar. I am unable to figure it out.

Comment: try  @batuhand's  answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use ExpansionTile widget for expandable areas.

For example

```
 ExpansionTile(
            title: Row(
              children: [
                Icon(Icons.home_rounded,
                  color: HexColor('#24591C'),),
                Text('Home',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontSize:   16,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700
                  ),),
                Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down_rounded,
                    size: 30,
                    color: HexColor('#444444')),
              ],
            ),
            children: [
              // the widgets you want to show on click
            ],
          ),
```

Comment: It didn't work the way I need this to. The project requires the drop-down to be formed in the body. This created the children within the appBar itself